# Как можно упростить данный код?

Tags: java, чистый-код

```java
public class Elevator {

    public int getCurrentFloor() {
        return currentFloor;
    }

    public void moveDown() {
        currentFloor = currentFloor > minFloor ? currentFloor - 1 : currentFloor;
    }

    public void moveUp() {
        currentFloor = currentFloor < maxFloor ? currentFloor + 1 : currentFloor;
    }

    public void move(int floor) {
        if (floor < minFloor || floor > maxFloor || floor == 0) {
            System.out.println("Данного этажа не существует");
        } else if (floor == currentFloor) {
            System.out.println("Вы уже находитесь на " + currentFloor + " этаже, невозможно поехать на тот же этаж");
        } else if (floor < currentFloor) {
            do {
                moveDown();
                if (currentFloor != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Лифт поедет на " + currentFloor + " этаж");
                }
            } while (floor != currentFloor);
        } else {
            do {
                moveUp();
                if (currentFloor != 0) {
                    System.out.println("Лифт поедет на " + currentFloor + " этаж");
                }
            } while (floor != currentFloor);
        }
    }

    public Elevator(int minFloor, int maxFloor) {
        this.minFloor = minFloor;
        this.maxFloor = maxFloor;
    }

    private final int minFloor;
    private final int maxFloor;
    private int currentFloor = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{
    do {
        if (условие) {
            moveDown();
        } else {
            moveUp();
        }
        if (currentFloor != 0) {
            System.out.println("Лифт поедет на " + currentFloor + " этаж");
        }

    }
    while (floor != currentFloor);
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, не так скопировал

Comment: Я просто исправил на то, как вы написали и получается так, что вверх он ведет отсчет, а вниз нет

Comment: потому что скобки неправильно были. Исправил.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, очень выручили)

Answer (score 2):

Мой вариант реализации метода `move`:

- указать "ошибочный" номер этажа в сообщении об ошибке
- использовать цикл `while` вместо `do-while`
- обязательно выводить сообщение о нахождении на текущем этаже

```java
public void move(int floor) {
    if (floor < minFloor || floor > maxFloor || floor == 0) {
        System.out.println("Данного этажа не существует: " + floor);
    } else while (floor != currentFloor) {
        if (floor < currentFloor) {
            moveDown();
        } else {
            moveUp();
        }
        if (currentFloor != 0) {
            System.out.println("Лифт едет на " + currentFloor + " этаж");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Вы находитесь на " + currentFloor + " этаже");
}
```

Тест:

```java
Elevator v = new Elevator(-2, 3);

v.move(-2);
v.move(5);
v.move(3);
v.move(0);
v.move(1);
v.move(1);
```

Результат:

```
Лифт едет на -1 этаж
Лифт едет на -2 этаж
Вы находитесь на -2 этаже
Данного этажа не существует: 5
Вы находитесь на -2 этаже
Лифт едет на -1 этаж
Лифт едет на 1 этаж
Лифт едет на 2 этаж
Лифт едет на 3 этаж
Вы находитесь на 3 этаже
Данного этажа не существует: 0
Вы находитесь на 3 этаже
Лифт едет на 2 этаж
Лифт едет на 1 этаж
Вы находитесь на 1 этаже
Вы находитесь на 1 этаже
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void move(int floor) {
    if (floor < minFloor || maxFloor < floor || floor == 0) {
        System.out.println("Данного этажа не существует");
    } else if (floor == currentFloor) {
        System.out.println("Вы уже находитесь на " + currentFloor + " этаже, невозможно поехать на тот же этаж");
    } else {
        int step = Integer.signum(floor - currentFloor);
        do {
            currentFloor += step;
            if (currentFloor != 0) {
                System.out.println("Лифт поедет на " + currentFloor + " этаж");
            }
        } while (floor != currentFloor);
    }
}
```